# I can't get the index.html to update with the new one

Tags: html

I uploaded the new index.html to my webspace but still see the old one.
I deleted it and tried again and still saw the old one.

What do I need to do?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the browser - the page is likely cached in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try a different client or browser, if it shows the new page it's probably your cache like nick said, if not then the old one is still actually on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an '?' to the end, and add some random text. To get like

http://www.server.com/index.html?blabla

This will force the browser to ignore the local cache, and ask for the new version of the index.html.

Each time you need to get the latest version, change the blabla to another thing.